# How do you search for issues resolved by a set of users (multiple users)?

Tags: jira, jql

I have a team of 3 people and I would like to search for the issues resolved by them, so that I can make a list of known issues. How can I search that in JIRA using Basic or Advanced search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It was simple. For the current user use the below query :

```
project = <project-name> AND status changed to "Resolved" by currentUser() ORDER BY updated DESC
```

For multiple users use :

```
project = <project-name> AND status changed to "Resolved" by ('<first-username>', '<second-username>', '<third-username>') ORDER BY updated DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the changes made by a single user, you can use a query like this:

```
project = MYPROJECT AND (resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY username1)
```

You can use the *CHANGED BY* operator to search for multiple users like this:

```
project = MYPROJECT 
AND (
  (resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY username1) 
  OR (resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY username2) 
  OR (resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY username3)
)
```

If you have many users to search for this becomes cumbersome though. It is also possible to search for multiple users like this:

```
project = MYPROJECT 
AND resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY ('username1', 'username2', 'username3')
```

If you're only interested in the changes since a certain date (e.g. the last 2 week) use subqueries like:

```
resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY username1 AFTER -2w
```

More documentation is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out that we could use : project = MYPROJECT AND resolution CHANGED TO fixed BY (currentUser(),'username1','username2')

Comment: Thanks, added it to the answer as well.